# Simplify with constraints does not work with square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I am trying to simplify a complex expression. One of the smallest parts of this expression is $\sqrt{1/(1-(1-m/k)^d)}\cdot\sqrt{(1-(1-m/k)^d)}$. For this smallest part it seems that `Simplify`does not work. Hence, I tried to use

`Simplify[Sqrt[1/(1-(1-m/k)^d)]*Sqrt[(1-(1-m/k)^d)],m>=1 && k>=1 && d>=1 && k>=4m]`

expecting $1$ as result. Instead, I get exactly the same expression that I provided in input. How is it possible?

---

*Note: I noticed that if I replace $d$ with a positive integer, it works without specifying that the variables are real.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why your assumptions didn't do the trick, but I often use the pattern `_ \[Element] Reals`, which works here:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[1/(1 - (1 - m/k)^d)]*Sqrt[(1 - (1 - m/k)^d)], _ \[Element] Reals]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: PowerExpand will do the jpb

Comment: Thank you ! Anyway, why did not work? It is about complex numbers and $d$? I noticed that if I replace $d$ with a positive integer, it works without specifying that the variables are real.

Comment: OK, thank you @RolandF, but I am working on a huge expression and it would be complicated to use PowerExpand on all single expression parts where I *manually* see that it can be used

Comment: Your assumptions have to assure, simply to check,  that the different expressions exclude a wedge along the negative real axis, so that all the square roots are maps to the right half plane Re z>0. Since this is nearly impossible to formulate, PowerExpand allsumes high school algebra power rules, implicitetly assuming that  all expressions are real positive, without any checks. You may use PowerExpand at no cost toegether with FullSimplify and check the results for identity on some critical complex exact numerical points in C.  Erreoneous simplfications yield imaginary multiples of Pi

Comment: Thank you @RolandF !

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Assuming[m >= 1 && k >= 1 && d >= 1 && k >= 4 m,
 Sqrt[1/(1 - (1 - m/k)^d)]*Sqrt[(1 - (1 - m/k)^d)] //
   ComplexExpand // Simplify]
```

[image]

However, the first condition is not feasible

```
FindInstance[(1 - m/k)^d > 1 && m >= 1 && k >= 1 && d >= 1 && k >= 4 m, 
   {d, k, m}, Reals]

(* {} *)
```

Adding the redundant condition `(1 - m/k)^d <= 1`

```
Assuming[m >= 1 && k >= 1 && d >= 1 && k >= 4 m && (1 - m/k)^d <= 1,
 Sqrt[1/(1 - (1 - m/k)^d)]*Sqrt[(1 - (1 - m/k)^d)] //
   ComplexExpand // Simplify]

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting. I would like to understand the reasons for this behavior so I will always know how to simplify any expression. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I can only guess that it gets caught in a logic loop. And "always know how to simplify any expression" is only a dream.

Comment: Sure, I meant *any "elementary"* expression, that is, formed by composing elementary functions. This must be possible with Mathematica.